# Trying to use Timer0 on Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega, arduino-ide, timers, avr, dmxsimple

I've recently been looking at Timers and I'm trying to generate a PWM frequency at 250000Hz using Timer0 on PIN 4. When I set OCR0A = 63 I get nothing from the light however when I set OCR0A = 125 it turns on ( 128000Hz - according to the formula in the datasheet unless I've been working it out wrong). What's the reason for it not working when OCR0A = 63

```
#include <DmxSimple.h>


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(250000);
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);  // SHIELD DRIVER OUTPUT ENABLE
  digitalWrite( 2 , HIGH); // SHEILD DE HIGH
  DDRG |= bit(DDG5); 



  TCCR0A = 0;
  TCCR0B = 0;
  TCNT0 =  0;

  TCCR0A = bit(COM0A1)| bit(COM0B1)| bit(WGM01)| bit(WGM00);
  TCCR0B = bit(WGM02) | bit(CS00);
  OCR0A = 63 ;
  OCR0B = 31;

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

(1,PORTG |= (1<<5));
(1,PORTG &= ~(1<<5));


}
```

Comment: Except for the loop code (that shouldn't be affecting anything, as it's using alternate pin function) and pointless COM0A1, I can't see any problem. Well, except one of my multimeters showed the wrong frequency, second one shows correct 248.76kHz and 50% pulse width.

Comment: @KIIV Could the DmxSimple library be causing a problem ? . I don't have an oscilloscope or multimeter to check the output frequency  but your multimeter showed 250kHz when OCR0A = 63 ?

Comment: DmxSimple uses Timer2 so it shouldn't be a problem. At least as far as you don't use anything `millis` related, like `delay` or so (because it's updated by Timer0 overflow and it won't happen with that changes)

Comment: I've made sure to leave any delays out . I'm not sure what the issue could be . Would it worth changing to see if it works in Fast PWM mode when `TOP = 0xff`

Comment: Btw, what light? Why do you need such short period?

Comment: It's a non branded DMX light that I had . The period is not necessary . I'm just trying to get a distinct modulated that signal that can be picked up by the photodiode. I was previously trying to get OOK modulation to work but was unable so I'm now trying PWM . Any suggestions would be much appreciated